# fnDrawCallback how to loop through each row

Tags: arrays, loops, datatable, datatables, callback

How do i loop through the enitre datset within the in datatables method?

```
 "fnFooterCallback": function (nFoot, aData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay) {
        $(aData).each(function (index) {
     $(".it").append("<div class='mapdata' id='" + nFoot + "B' title='" + aData[index][14] + "|" + aData[index][15] + "' >");
        });
    },
```

The above works if the pagination is removed. But if `iDisplayLength` is set to 25 for example then it only goes through 25 records, not all 100 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"fnFooterCallback": function (nFoot, aData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay) {

        $(aData).each(function (index) {
            $(".it").append("<div class='mapdata' id='" + nFoot + "B' title='" + aData[index][14] + "|" + aData[index][15] + "' data-id='true' data-id2='" + aData[index][1] + "' data-isapprove='" + aData[index][12] + "' ><div class='gTab1'><div class='info'><div class='maptitle'>" + aData[index][1] + "</div><div class='location'></div></div></div ></div >");
        });
    },
```

The above did it